# Mongoosastic search function undefined when using typescript

Tags: typescript, mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoose, mongoosastic

I'm using `mongoose v6.0.0`, and `mongoosastic v5.0.0` and `typescript` when I try the following code after initializing the plugin and trying to set the types correctly it still tells me that `PageModel.search` and other functions introduced by the plugin are `undefined`.

```js
import mongoose, { Schema, Document } from 'mongoose';
import mongoosastic, { MongoosasticModel, MongoosasticDocument } from 'mongoosastic'

export interface IPage extends Document, MongoosasticDocument {
  user: string;
  permissions: {
    [key: string]: {
      read: boolean;
      write: boolean;
      admin: boolean;
      email: string;
    };
  };
  style: {};
  data: {
    blockType: string;
    properties: {};
    children: [];
  }[];
}

const PageSchema = new Schema({
  user: String,
  permissions: {},
  style: {},
  data: [
    {
      blockType: String,
      properties: {},
      children: [],
    },
  ],
});

// -=- Elastic Search -=-
// ~ Check if Elastic Search info exists
if (!process.env.ELASTICSEARCH_URL) throw Error('Missing Elastic Search URL');

// ~ Add Elastic Search plugin
PageSchema.plugin(
  mongoosastic,
  {
    clientOptions: {
      nodes: [
        process.env.ELASTICSEARCH_URL,
      ]
    },
    transform: (doc: IPage) => {
      
    },
  }
);

const PageModel = (mongoose.models.page || mongoose.model('page', PageSchema)) as mongoose.Model<IPage, MongoosasticModel<IPage>>;

// ~ PageModel.search is undefined here

export default PageModel;
```

I've tried upgrading mongoose to the latest version and upgrading the mongoose types by the [documentation](https://mongoosastic.github.io/mongoosastic/index.html) doesn't seem to have much info.

Answer (score 0):

Just miss typed the PageModel I switched the code from

```js
const PageModel = (mongoose.models.page || mongoose.model('page', PageSchema)) as mongoose.Model<IPage, MongoosasticModel<IPage>>;
```

to

```js
const PageModel = (mongoose.models.page || mongoose.model('page', PageSchema)) as MongoosasticModel<IPage>;
```